# Цикл в BAT-файле

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, скрипт

Здрaвствуйте. Есть консольное приложение, которое конвертирует файл из одного формата в другой `file_1.dat -> file_1.txt`

```
cd C:\Program Files\app\
app.exe convert -aaa -bbb -in C:\folder\file_1.dat -out C:\folder\file_1.txt -K 11111 -S 22222
```

Вопрос: какой нужен BAT-цикл, который найдёт все файлы в папке `folder` с расширением `.dat` и по каждому из них пройдётся этой командой? Предварительно склеивать файлы нельзя, т.к. они после этого «ломаются».

Меняются только имена входного и выходного файла. Что должно происходить в процессе работы пакетного файла:

```
app.exe convert -abc -asd -in C:\folder\file_1.dat -out C:\folder\file_1.txt -K 12345 -S 12345
app.exe convert -abc -asd -in C:\folder\file_2.dat -out C:\folder\file_2.txt -K 12345 -S 12345
app.exe convert -abc -asd -in C:\folder\file_3.dat -out C:\folder\file_3.txt -K 12345 -S 12345
app.exe convert -abc -asd -in C:\folder\file_4.dat -out C:\folder\file_4.txt -K 12345 -S 12345
```

Можете подсказать, как написать данный BAT-сценарий?

Comment: Справку к команде **forfiles** читайте. Например, **forfiles /p c:\folder /m *.dat /c "cmd /c C:\Program Files\app\app.exe @path c:\folder\@fname.txt"**

Answer (score 0):

Создайте батник с нижеследующим содержимым в каталоге где вам нужно переименовать файлы. В вашей задаче это каталог по адресу C:\folder и все файлы будут конвертироваться, как выхотели причем не важно сколько их в этой папке.

```
@echo off
set app="C:\Program Files\app\app.exe"
for %%f in (*.dat) do ( 
    %app% convert -abc -asd -in "%%~f" -out "%%~nf.txt" -K 12345 -S 12345   
)
```

если удалить первую сточку @echo off, то вы увидете результат работы программы, как на скриншоте:

---

[image: результат работы программы]